# Will the equations derived for dark and bright fringes remain the same in this case too, or will there be changes?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, interference, double-slit-experiment, geometry

We know in YDSE experiment we calculate position of white and dark fringe by calculating the path difference using Pythagoras theorem and equating it to $n\lambda$ and $\frac{2n-1}{2}\lambda$ respectively ,i.e.,
$$\Delta x=D[1+\frac{(y+\frac{d}{2})^2}{D^2}]^{0.5}-D[1+\frac{(y-\frac{d}{2})^2}{D^2}]^{0.5}$$ Which simplifies to $$\Delta x=\frac{yd}{D}$$ And,
$$n\lambda =\frac{yd}{D}\,\,\, (bright)$$
$$\frac{2n-1}{2}\lambda =\frac{yd}{D}\,\,\, (dark)$$
But this is true only when the plane containing the sources and the plane of screen are parallel to each other. So what happens actually when the plane containing the sources and the plane of screen are perpendicular to each other like shown below.

[image]

Will the equations derived for dark and bright fringes remain the same in this case too, or will there be changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there will be fringes.  And you can use the same formulas to calculate the positions.